# Chart Plugin for Titanium Studio

Tags: plugins, charts, titanium

Can I know is there any other chart plugin other than Raphael? I want to try other plugin where Raphael is not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why Raphael may be a wrong choice for you:

1. You want performance.
2. You want real charting.

### Performance

Titanium is an interpreted engine. Anything other than basic website and animation that runs in a WebView is going to be slow, especially when you have data funneling back and forth between the WebView and the app. You may want to look at using a native module instead: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4968?1402012027

If your charting needs are constrained to a (very) limited set of permutations, the alternative is simply to use a bunch of ImageViews to create your chart.

### Charting

Raphael is actually not a charting library, but a graphics library. I think you were looking for [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/). If you want to chart in a WebView, any web-based charting libraries work just as well, like Dojo Charting, YUI Charts, and Google Chart Tools.